# Tomcat 8 JSP Validation

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, tomcat8

I have a lot of JSPs in my app, and we recently upgraded to Tomcat 8 and Java 8. Occasionally I'll encounter this error

```
The JSP specification requires that an attribute name is preceded by whitespace
```

on a JSP page and it will cause the page to not load at all. This is obviously a huge problem, its not some small warning, it entirely breaks the app in random ways. (i.e. "random" pages) I need some tool to help me validate my JSPS. Eclipse has a JSP validation tool, but I run it on this page and it tells me everything is fine. Do I need to upgrade the validator? How do I do that? Is there maybe some other 3rd party tool I can run across my WEB-INF that tells me about these issues?

Comment: Try compiling all JSPs with an Ant script: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jasper-howto.html#Web_Application_Compilation

Comment: @Andreas your comment is an answer, so please consider posting it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try compiling all JSPs with an Ant script:
  https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jasper-howto.html#Web_Application_Compilation

Comment: To anyone else out there thinking of doing this, set your webapp.path to the path INSIDE tomcat, NOT in your development workspace. If your environment is as complicated as mine is this will save you hours of troubleshooting strange errors.